# How can i connect and access gcloud mysql?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Also, i need to connect with the same project hosted app with the cluster.
and access the database.
i don't know which IP i give in the mysql.createconnection in my app.
in my node.js app

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({host:"IP",user:"username",password: "password",database:"databasename"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to connect to Cloud SQL" is kind of a broad question, and you haven't given very many details as to your environment, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

First there are generally 3 ways to connect to Cloud SQL - via Environment connectors, Private IP, Public IP.

### Environment Connectors (App Engine & Cloud Functions)

If you are using Google App Engine or Google Functions, you should use the `/cloudsql` socket provided by the environment. See this [page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) here for examples.

### Private IP (Compute or Kubernetes Engine)

To connect via Private IP, your app needs to have access to a [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/). This can be either a [Compute VM](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc) or a [GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc). Then you app can access the "Private IP" for the instance just like it would a local database.

### Public IP (Anything with access to the internet)

Finally, you can connect via Public IP. This can be done as long as you have access to the internet, but by default public connections need to be authenticated. This can be done 3 different ways:

1. Using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)
2. Using an [SSL cert](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance)
3. Whitelisting an [IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AkshayBarad - Please make sure to accept if it answered your question (or upvote if it helped you on someone else's question). Thanks :)